# SVN commit by change date and time

Tags: svn

I have committed yesterday some changes to SVN, and that time my system date and time was changed to one day ahead. Now on looking to SVN logs, I am not able to find changes committed before yesterday, it is showing changes from 2 days before, all changes committed Yesterday and before yesterday have not been shown in repository.

One more thing is that this changes are shown at another system. Only at my system I am unable to see those. I have uninstalled subversion and svn and reinstall again, but still repository not showing latest changes.

I am using TortoiseSVN-1.6.6.17493-x64-svn-1.6.6.msi and svn-1.4.3-setup.exe version.

How can I get back those changes?

Thanks

Comment: You should try to use compatible version of client and server. This should not be the reason, is a problem here or there, because features that could  be available by the client cannot be supported by the server. What is your result of saying: `svn log <dir>` on the command line and the corresponding `TortoiseSVN > Show log`. Are there any differences?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking out to a new location?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know TortoiseSVN so these tips are for the standalone client (normally best way of doing hard core debugging as GUIs sometimes hides problems and limit options.

Start of with `svn info` to make sure you're in a working copy and also to get the url. The output would be something like
    Path: .
    URL: svn://your.server/your.repository/directory
    Repository Root: svn://your.server/your.repository

then do a `svn log` on the repository root (in the example above `svn log svn://your.server/your.repository`. Now all changes will be shown, both for commits to trunk, branches and tags (or whatever layout you use).

See if you find your commit there.

If not, try to do a new commit, change something and commit as you did yesterday. Retry the above `svn log`. Is your new commit showing up?

Also make sure that you did in fact commit. Go to your directory and do a `svn stat` to see if any files are changed.

These steps should give you at least some information.